# In Kentico -- how to display data from a form on a web page?

Tags: kentico

Okay...so I am saving records from an in-line form in a table (a form table).  Now if I want to display the records or a given record back on a webpage -- how do you go about doing this.  I found one post where it is suggested to use a Repeater web part and query the form's table.  So, with that suggestion, where does the query get written?  There is no query option on forms.  Having a tough time connecting the dots on this one.  Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Query can be in any "container" page type. For example there is root (CMS.Root) page type which holds common queries and transformations. When you create a page type you can tell the system that this page type is only a container without custom fields. So you can create a new container type or use an existing one. Define your query in the container and use *repeater with custom query web part*.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. Use "Repeater With Custom Query" web part for display form data on web page
2. First create Container page type from Page Types application ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/k5gttp))
3. Drag web part into page and configure below 
   a. Click New button from Query name option and write Query(see [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/k5gu6y))
   b. You can replace your Form table name in sample query screenshot
4. Write transformation and save this into Container ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/k5gvzx))

I hope this help you.

Comment: Vasu.  Thanks...great instructions. This works!! Thank you.